# Grid View - Capturing Scroll Position

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

My requirement is to have a grid that moves along with a grid view when I scroll through a grid view.
I used WinRT XAML Toolkit to get the Gridview descendants http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/ - VisualTreeHelperExtensions.

This is the code I have to get the scrollbar within the GridView.

```
    var scrollViewer = itemGridView.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();
    var scrollbars = scrollViewer.GetDescendantsOfType<ScrollBar>().ToList();
    var horizontalBar = scrollbars.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal);
    horizontalBar.Scroll += horizontalBar_Scroll
```

My problem is - the scrollViewer is always null. Setting breakpoints I see, the count of ScrollViewers inside the GridView is 0.

How do I get a reference to the scrollbar inside the gridview? Or is there another way to move the grid element whenever the gridview is scrolled?

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason to this behavior. I was performing this query in the Page constructor. I now have it when the itemGridView is completely Loaded.

```
   itemGridView.Loaded += itemGridView_Loaded;
```

Quote from MSDN:

> Loaded:
>   Occurs when a FrameworkElement has been constructed and added to the object tree, and is ready for interaction. (Inherited from FrameworkElement)

Thanks